# Express the sentence in predicate logic

Tags: logic, predicate

I'm new to predicate logic and I'm not sure if I understand it.

Could someone verify my solutions? If something is wrong, please tell me why and how it can be improved.

Express the sentences in predicate logic:

1. Some people feel offended when they hear the truth.

`ƎX∀Y(says_true(Y,X) ⇒ feels_offended(X,Y))`

or

`ƎX(hears(X, truth) ⇒ feels_offended(X))`

I'm not sure which one is better.

2. Enemies of our enemies are our friends.

`∀X∀Y∀Z(enemies(X,Y) ∧ enemies(Y,Z) ⇒ friends(X,Z))`

3. A brother of ones father is his uncle.

`∀X∀Y∀Z(brother(X,Y) ∧ father(Y,Z) ⇒ uncle(X,Z))`

4. There are animals that do not have natural enemies.

`ƎX∀Y(is_animal(X) ⇒ ¬natural_enemies(X, Y))`

5. There are some who raise children of other people.

`ƎXƎY(¬is_parent(X,Y) ∧ is_raising(X,Y))`

6. If a politician has supporters, he also has haters.

`∀XƎYƎZ(is_politician(X) ∧ supporter(X,Y) ⇒ hater(X,Z))`